# FIFA 17 performance issue with sound

Tags: fifa-17

I am having a peculiar issue with FIFA 17. My game used to run on 40-50 fps with **1920x1080** resolution, other settings at **Auto** and FPS lock at 60fps.

But then it started lagging and sometimes it would just stop rendering completely with only the background stadium noises playing. This stopped when **I plugged in my earphones into the audio jack of my laptop**

Now is runs fine (at around the same or lower fps with some lags when the focus is near the goalposts) but I can't understand **why this is happening?**

Does it have anything to do with the audio drivers?

My system config:

- Win 10 on Lenovo z51-70
- RAM - 8GB
- Processor - i7 (5th gen) @ 2.4GHz
- Graphic Card - AMD Radeon R9 M375 (4GB)

Answer (score -1):

At first looking at the system requirements that you have posted, I think you should be good and there shouldn't be any problem running the game. But, because you are still getting problems, I suspect there is some issue with your Graphics Card and/or Audio Card. I suggest you to visit this website:

[Can You RUN It?](https://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri)

Test your computer with the help of this website. This should tell you whether your computer is at par with the requirements of the game.

Source: Own experience and web search.